# Survey Monkey user responses over 100 on free trial

Tags: surveymonkey

I am creating this survey to track exit interviews for my job. I am wondering, and could not find anywhere, if i fill up my 100 responses for one survey then what happens? Will I not be able to ever view the next ones over 100? Can I just delete old survey responses and view new ones? Will these new ones be recorded in the data of the surveys? Do I have to make another identical survey to record more responses?
Thanks

Comment: Yes you can continue to collect responses, but can't see them. If you delete old ones I'm not sure if that gives you access to future ones (I believe it would). If you need more than 100 responses I would consider expensing a paid plan with your employer.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty clearly described on their [pricing page.](https://www.surveymonkey.com/pricing/)

> With a free plan, you can collect more than 100 responses, but you can only view the first 100 responses. Upgrade at any time to access additional responses. Our STANDARD Monthly plan includes 1000 responses per monthly billing cycle across all your surveys with a $0.15 charge per additional response. All annual plans include an unlimited number of responses.

If you need more than their free trial offers, pay for the service.